# Does the following structure cause memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Hi I have web application hosted on following enviornment.
Single Core,1 GB RAM,40 GB Harddisk, 700 GB Bandwidth. Currenlty 4-6 users are working on it. There is a form Manage Policy where all the policy are getting diplayed in the gridview. For this I am returning a datatable from static method. My structuer is as follow,

```
private void BindGrid(object sortExp) // Method to bind Grid
{

    DataTable dt = PolicyAccess.GetAllPolicy(some parameters for filter);
    GRV1.DataSource = dt; 
    GRV1.DataBind();
    dt.Dispose();

}
```

I have following static method in non static class which return datatable

```
public static DataTable GetAllPolicy(string pmPolicyNo, int type)
{
    // get a configured DbCommand object
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
    // set the stored procedure name
    comm.CommandText = "proc_docGetAllPolicy";

    // create a new parameter
    DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@pmPolicyNo";
    param.Value = pmPolicyNo;
    param.DbType = DbType.String;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);


    // create a new parameter
    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@Type";
    param.Value = type;
    param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    // execute the stored procedure and save the results in a DataTable
    DataTable table = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand(comm);
    return table;
}
```

I have following static method in a static class "GenericDataAccess" to execute command

```
public static DataTable ExecuteSelectCommand(DbCommand command)
{
    // The DataTable to be returned 
    DataTable table;
    // Execute the command making sure the connection gets closed in the end
    try
    {
        // Open the data connection 
        command.Connection.Open();
        // Execute the command and save the results in a DataTable
        DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);

        // Close the reader 
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utilities.LogError(ex);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the connection
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
    return table;
}

// creates and prepares a new DbCommand object on a new connection
public static DbCommand CreateCommand()
{
    // Obtain the database provider name
    string dataProviderName = NandiConfiguration.DbProviderName;
    // Obtain the database connection string
    string connectionString = NandiConfiguration.DbConnectionString;
    // Create a new data provider factory
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.
    GetFactory(dataProviderName);
    // Obtain a database specific connection object
    DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
    // Set the connection string
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    // Create a database specific command object
    DbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
    // Set the command type to stored procedure
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // Return the initialized command object
    return comm;
}
```

does the above structure(static object and method) cause memory leak ?

If there are concurrent users, will there be possibility of user seeing other user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared data can be an issue. But there are no `static` fields mentioned, so this is safe for concurrent users on separate threads.

Memory leak - no. High memory consumption, maybe, but that just depends on the amount of data and the efficiency of the db design (W.R.T. indexes etc).

CPU cores, RAM, Hard disk, Bandwidth, number of users are all irrelevant to your question.

Comment: does returning a data table will cost high memory consumption ?

Comment: "that just depends on the amount of data and the efficiency of the db design"